# How to subscribe to updates in Telegram Api?

Tags: c#, telegram

My question is a copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455627/how-to-subscribe-to-chat-updates-in-telegram-api)

However, I don't understand how to use the answer given there

[The library I am using](https://github.com/aarani/TgSharp) already implements what the answer says

```
TelegramClient.cs    
var config = new TLRequestGetConfig();
var request = new TLRequestInitConnection()
{
    ApiId = apiId,
    AppVersion = "1.0.0",
    DeviceModel = "PC",
    LangCode = "en",
    Query = config,
    SystemVersion = "Win 10.0",
    SystemLangCode = "en",
    LangPack = ""
};
var invokewithLayer = new TLRequestInvokeWithLayer() { Layer = 108, Query = request };
await sender.Send(invokewithLayer, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
await sender.Receive(invokewithLayer, token).ConfigureAwait(false);

dcOptions = ((TLConfig)invokewithLayer.Response).DcOptions.ToList();
```

Where does Telegram send updates?

I thought the updates could be read in the `TcpClient` that the `TelegramClient` has, but no, it doesn't receive updates

The [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/updates) says:

> Update events are sent to an authorized user into the last active
> connection (except for connections needed for downloading / uploading
> files).
>
> So to start receiving updates the client needs to init
> connection and call API method, e.g. to fetch current state.

**But where does it send updates? How do I subscribe to them / how do I read them?**

P.S. `updates.getDifference` is not what i'm looking for

### UPD

I've already looked at all the source code, but the most I found is `processMessage` in [MtProtoSender](https://github.com/aarani/TgSharp/blob/master/src/TgSharp.Core/Network/MtProtoSender.cs#L179), but it only handles manually sent requests

[Another library](https://github.com/egramtel/tdsharp) based on [TDLib](https://github.com/tdlib/td) handles incoming updates. Trying to understand how it does it, I got to [this point](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/tdutils/td/utils/queue.h#L357). What is going on here and how can I do the same in TLSharp I do not understand

[Same problem](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/issues/40) in another library which was solved but doesn't work for me